# Work flow when editing files in /var/www. Constantly needing to input "sudo" commands

Tags: php, linux, workflows, apache

I installed Apache2 and PHP5 last night on my fresh Linux Mint machine.

I created a folder and created a simple `index.php` file with a call to `phpinfo()` to test out the installation and every works correctly.

However when I open the file with Sublime Text 2 or any other editor, I cannot save my changes. I can use the `sudo nano` command to open it with super user privileges and I can save just fine.

The same goes with Mercurial. I cannot `hg commit` because of permissions. I can only `sudo hg commit`.

Is this how the basic workflow is supposed to be? If I run the `chmod` command and recursively give `777` permissions to the folders and files within Apache can run it just fine, but if it's a dynamically created file (*created by my web app*) then it seems Apache cannot access or run it. I have to run the `chmod` command **again**!

Any suggestions on what I should do? I feel like 30% of my time is spent on redundant processes that shouldn't be done at all.

Comment: **DO NOT SET MODE 777** - This is a gaping security hole!

Comment: @Daenyth: Oh I know, it's just what was easiest for my dev machine. That's why I'm asking the question - I want to know what the proper workflow is.

Comment: Is the dev server on a virtual machine? If so, I tend to ensure the 'web docs directory' is a [shared directory](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html) and edit the files on my host machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've indidcated this is your dev environment, so beyond Daenyth's suggestion of using source control (which you should definitely do) I'd suggest doing a little indirection.

In other words, simply use a symbolic link from /var/www to a working directory that you have permission to work in.  Then you can mess around in your working directory as needed and apache will happily serve it up.

Comment: I've never heard of a "symbolic link" before. Does that means Apache will run a PHP script from anywhere as long as there is a Symbolic Link set up?

Comment: @Serg If you have a symlink `/var/www -> /home/serg/wwwdev/` and `index.php` is in `wwwdev`, then as far as Apache knows, `/var/www/index.php` exists, as does everything else in `wwwdev`.  So any php scripts that could run under `/var/www/` will still run under the new location, because Apache thinks they're still in the first location.

Answer (score 1):

You should store your code in source control (mercurial for example). Edit it on a local copy and push to your remote repository, then pull the changes to the server as needed.

Make a user/group for the web process to run under, and set the permissions & ownership for that user/group. Any new files will be owned by the process's user, so when configured correctly it should work just fine.